# Can I use Google Tag Manager with the new Google Sites?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-sites-2016

I have a new Google sites and already use Google analytics with it but I also would like to use Google Tag Manager. Any one know a way to make that work?

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You could technically add an "Embed" element to the site and add your GTM snippet there. But you can really only trigger tags when the embedded element loads similar to a page view. I believe these elements are similar to iFrames so I don't think you could get any data from the parent URL either.

Otherwise, you can still add Google Analytics by going to "Settings".